# How can I use quill-cursors library with socket.io for real-time collaboration with multiple users in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, quill

Good evening everyone.
I am new here and this is my first time asking in this platform and I am looking for a little bit of guidance about an issue.
I am using Quill Js with socket.io to enable real-time collaboration, and so far everything works perfectly. Now, I tried using quill-cursors library to show users' cursors in real time, and each user, whenever they join the document, they get assigned a new color.

Now, I read the demo of this library and they were using it with two editors and two users, but when  I tried to do the same with every user that joins the document, many errors showed up and most of the time, the editor just froze, and I believe that it is a problem of syntax and code positioning because honestly I did not understand how it worked.
Therefore, if anyone can help me or just guide me on how I can apply this for all the users that join, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you very much for your help and your time, and I appreciate in advance every answer.